# how to perform complicated manipulations on scala datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark-dataset

I am fairly new to scala and having come from a sql and pandas background the dataset objects in scala are giving me a bit of trouble.

I have a dataset that looks like the following...

```
|car_num|      colour|
+-----------+---------+
|      145| c|
|      132| p|
|      104| u|
|      110| c|
|      110| f|
|      113| c|
|      115| c|
|       11| i|
|      117| s|
|      118| a|
```

I have loaded it as a dataset using a case class that looks like the following

```
case class carDS(carNum: String, Colour: String)
```

Each car_num is unique to a car, many of the cars have multiple entries. The colour column refers to the colour the car was painted.

I would like to know how to add a column that gives the total number of paint jobs a car has had without being green (g) for example.

So far I have tried this.

```
carDS
  .map(x => (x.carNum, x.Colour))
  .groupBy("_1")
  .count()
  .orderBy($"count".desc).show()
```

But I believe it just gives me a count column of the number of times the car was painted. Not the longest sequential amount of times the car was painted without being green.

I think I might need to use a function in my query like the following

```
def colourrun(sq: String): Int = {
  println(sq)
  sq.mkString(" ")
    .split("g")
    .filter(_.nonEmpty)
    .map(_.trim)
    .map(s => s.split(" ").length)
    .max
}
```

but I am unsure where it should go.

Ultimately if car 102 had been painted r, b, g, b, o, y, r, g
I would want the count column to give 4 as the answer.

How would I do this?
thanks

Comment: You can't rely on the rows coming in any particular order. So, the answer `7` for your  example is as valid as is `4` .... and to get that, you just `filterNot(_.Colour == "g")`

Comment: Ok thank you, is that true if the rows are already order or I have the dates? 
How would you do any sort of complicated search? What do I need to read up on? Do I use a Ugf? Or can I use a look to go through the dataset and collect entries of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that involves grouping the paint jobs for a given car into monotonically numbered groups separated by paint jobs of color "g", followed by a couple of `groupBy/agg`s for the max count of paint jobs between being paint jobs of color "g".

(Note that a `timestamp` column is being added to ensure a deterministic ordering of the rows in the dataset.)

```
val ds = Seq(
  ("102", "r", 1), ("102", "b", 2), ("102", "g", 3), ("102", "b", 4), ("102", "o", 5), ("102", "y", 6), ("102", "r", 7), ("102", "g", 8),
  ("145", "c", 1), ("145", "g", 2), ("145", "b", 3), ("145", "r", 4), ("145", "g", 5), ("145", "c", 6), ("145", "g", 7)
).toDF("car_num", "colour", "timestamp").as[(String, String, Long)]

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val win = Window.partitionBy("car_num").orderBy("timestamp")

ds.
  withColumn("group", sum(when($"colour" === "g", 1).otherwise(0)).over(win)).
  groupBy("car_num", "group").agg(
    when($"group" === 0, count("group")).otherwise(count("group") - 1).as("count")
  ).
  groupBy("car_num").agg(max("count").as("max_between_g")).
  show
// +-------+-------------+
// |car_num|max_between_g|
// +-------+-------------+
// |    102|            4|
// |    145|            2|
// +-------+-------------+
```

---

An alternative to using the DataFrame API is to apply `groupByKey` to the Dataset followed by [`mapGroups`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset@mapGroups%5BU%5D(f:(K,Iterator%5BV%5D)=%3EU)(implicitevidence$4:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D) like below:

```
ds.
  map(c => (c.car_num, c.colour)).
  groupByKey(_._1).mapGroups{ case (k, iter) =>
    val maxTuple = iter.map(_._2).foldLeft((0, 0)){ case ((cnt, mx), c) =>
      if (c == "g") (0, math.max(cnt, mx)) else (cnt + 1, mx)
    }
    (k, maxTuple._2)
  }.
  show
  // +---+---+
  // | _1| _2|
  // +---+---+
  // |102|  4|
  // |145|  2|
  // +---+---+
```

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks so much for the reply. This is great. I am wondering though if there is a functional way to do it without the use of SQL? For example. If i where to do this problem in python with pandas. I would write a for loop that would iterate over each car number and extract all rows for each one. Then collect the colours in a list and work out the the count value I am after and save it. After doing this for each carnumber I would then add the list of counts to the dataframe as a column and I would have my solution

Comment: I would like to atempt to solve the problem that way but I am unsure how to write a loop like that in scala and also if it is possible to append to lists and then add the data back into the dataset at the end. If you coulda help a little with that then U should have answered this question :)

Comment: If you must do down the path of using non-SQL-based transformations, please see my expanded answer for a solution using `groupByKey/mapGroups`.